# How can I recover my village after someone saved over my Google+ account savegame?

Tags: clash-of-clans

So someone saved a level 2 to my Google+ account and now I can't transfer my game to my new phone because there isn't a second way to restore my progress.

It caused me to get kicked from my clan and I've shamefully spent a lot of money on this game! I don't want to lose it. Is there any way to restore it?

Comment: Can you give more details? How many devices are there and what is the progress on each device?

Answer (score 3):

You should submit a help request to the Clash of Clans Player Support team.

As per the [Supercell Game Support](https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/421502-I-ve-lost-my-village-Can-I-get-it-back-) page (emphasis mine):

> We recommend that you play only one village per device, and that you attach your village to a unique Game Center or Google+ account of your own. If you load multiple villages on a single device, you may lose access to one or more of the villages in the process -- so we're inclined to advise against doing that.
>
> **If you have lost your village for some reason, please submit a help request to Clash of Clans Player Support.**
>
> You can submit a help request by sending a message from the game on your device. To send an in-game message, tap the in-game settings icon, select "Help and Feedback", and then tap "Report an Issue". That will assure we have all the necessary data to make the recovering process as quick as possible.
>
> Please include the following information in the message, so that we can locate your village:
>
> - *Exact* name of the two villages
> - *Exact* level of the two villages
> - *Exact* Town Hall level of the two villages
> - *Exact* clan name of the two villages
>
> Please note that the information is required for both the lost village, and the village that you currently have on your device.